# i assign value to subclass of NSManagedObject but the property not assign

Tags: core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobject

i create a subclass of managedObject from the core data file.its created a new class name Books.

i make in the code property book to the Book class and write that code:

_book.name = title.text;

but the name property is not assign and show me null value when i'm trying 
NSlog(@" %@", _book.name)

what could be the problem??????

Comment: you need to post the code for your subclass.

Comment: Is `name` defined in the data model, or you just added the property to the class?

Comment: name is part of the class